# HTML video detection

Tags: html, html-parsing, html5-video

I got a HTML-document and I want to extract every single URL of a video-file. Whats the best way to do this, since there are different HTML-versions and different possibilities to embed a video-file into a HTML-document. For this purpose I'd use the Html Agility Pack (c#).

Answer (score -1):

You should parse the html with a regular expression for getting the video URL's.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :)

Comment: That's not really helpful.

Comment: As far as I know, there are 4 possibilities to embed a video into a HTML-document:
<href ...>, <embed ...>, <object ...> and since HTML5 theres the video-tag. Do you know different ways to deal with videos?